# How to use percentages to make text occur less or more frequently?

Tags: objective-c, percentage

I want to know if there is a way to use percentages to make text occur less or more frequently, like if I want word1 to occur 1% of the time, word2 40% of the time and word3 to occur 59% of the time.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do ,can you add some explanations of what are you doing ?

Comment: I want to have a button the user presses and there is a 1% chance of one word popping up and a 99% chance of the other word popping up. Or so, this is just simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to run RNG (Random) (based on time or something dynamic) lets say from 1 - 100 
then you can check if the number you got is less or equal to 1 put the word that you want to be with 1% chance etc...
if you got another number bigger than 1 then put the word that has 99% of occurrence -> it is simplified.

however it might be not the best solution because random is not really random (but it is another problem ).

back to the original question 
word1 -> `1% is <=1`
word2 -> `40% is >1 && <= 40` 
word3 -> could be `else`

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple percentages, randomly pick a number between [0,99], and "assign" ranges to different outcomes.  Simply,

```
- (NSString*)randomWord
{
    uint32_t r = arc4random_uniform(100);
    if (r < 1) return word1;
    if (r < 41) return word2;
    return word3;
}
```